# Does the SQL standard define the behaviour of integer/floating point overflow?

Tags: overflow, sql

I tried googling but it seems each database handles this differently. Does the SQL standard actually state what behaviour happens for value overflows?

Sources:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. Recently had a look at the SQL 2003 standard but nothing like that stood out. I doubt it highly.

Speaking from experience they all will vary in how they handle it.